# Filter on concated column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query

```
select name || ' ' || sure_name from users
```

which has this result

```
'test test'
'test1 test1'
...
```

I need to create a filter for this query. But I'm wondering what would be best way of creating it. I came up with this:

```
select name || ' ' || sure_name from users
where name || ' ' || sure_name = 'test test'
```

But I'm wondering how efficient will be this query as the concating happens twice (in the select statement and also in the where statement)

**EDIT**

the filter could look like

```
like '%test t'
```

Comment: You should rename that column to `sur_name`. A sure name is something different than a surname ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concatenation itself is not the problem, but the access to the rows.

For example, if you have an index on sure_name or on name, it is better to query with separate columns.

```
select name || ' ' || sure_name from users
where name ='test' and sure_name = 'test';
```

But if you don't have any indexes, don't bother. The performance will be roughly the same with your query.

However, if you add an index

```
create index fbi_full_name on users(name || ' ' || sure_name)
```

your query will perform better.

Comment: I've seen the edit. Such queries(starting with '%') can't use the index. The index can be used with queryes with `like 'Jo%'` (knowing the starting pattern)

Answer (score 3):

Test each field separately so that if you have indexes on `name` or `sure_name` then these indexes can be used more efficiently:

```
SELECT name || ' ' || sure_name
FROM users
WHERE name = 'test'
AND sure_name = 'test'
```

Note also that if the name or the suname could contain spaces then the two queries can give different results.

Comment: @user49126 Mark Byers told you the best solution. Please explain the correction of the question.

Answer (score 3):

In such a case, I prefer to express this using a subquery:

```
select *
from (select (name || ' ' || sure_name) as newname
      from users
     ) t
where newname = 'test test'
```

That way, my `where` logic is a little bit more isolated from the variable creation logic.  I find it easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from (
   select name || ' ' || sure_name as fullname
   from users
) 
where fullname like '%test t'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query :

```
select name || ' ' || sure_name 
from users
where (name || ' ' || sure_name) like '%test t'
```

Comment: I tried it on **`SQL SERVER R2`** it worked. Here is my **[SQL FIDDLE for SQL SERVER R2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb8fb/1)**. **UPDATE** It also worked on **`Oracle 11g R2`**, here is the **[SQL FIDDLE for ORACLE 11g R2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb8fb/2)**

Comment: Sure it works. but: 1. is the same query as OP. 2.Does not add any explanation, nothing new to user. 3. you have an upvote. I downvoted. **Improve your response with something useful.** And, 4: Don't be furious. :) I got downvotes also. Some users don't feel useful some answers :)

Comment: @FlorinGhita **AGREED**, But actually i didn't saw the OP.

Comment: That's your fault, his query was there at the beginning :)